# How to replace part of the Redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a packageReducer which keeps the packageType and packageList related details. once the details are fetched from the server I need to replace the initial state values with the new values that are been fetched. As an example, if the packageLists are been fetched I need to replace only the "packageList"

 Below is my PackageState reducer,

```
const initialState = {
    packageList: packageListInitialState,
    packageTypes: [{title: 'Select Package Type', value: ''}],
};

export default function packageState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:{
            return Object.assign( {}, state,  action.payload );
        }

        case FETCH_PACKAGE_TYPES_SUCCESS:{
           return Object.assign( {}, state,  action.payload );
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The way I have implemented I think im replacing the entire state, Can someone let me know how I can achieve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the actionCreators to the question? It would help to know the content of the action.payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not:

```js
var state = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
var newData = {a: 4, b: 5}
console.log(Object.assign( {}, state,  newData )) // { a: 4, b: 5, c: 3 }
```

> Properties in the target object will be overwritten by properties in the sources if they have the same key.  Later sources' properties will similarly overwrite earlier ones.  ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

So, as long as your payload contains the keys that you really want to update, you are safe. You can also do it in a simpler way if you use ES6's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (I'm assuming your payload looks like `{packageList: data}`):

```
const initialState = {
    packageList: packageListInitialState,
    packageTypes: [{title: 'Select Package Type', value: ''}],
};

export default function packageState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:{
            return {...state, ...action.payload};
        }

        case FETCH_PACKAGE_SETTINGS_SUCCESS:{
           return {...state,  ...action.payload};
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if I am to set the initial state again, should I do it like below?
`return {...state, packageList: packageListInitialState };`

Comment: You mean the default case? No, you need to have a special case that returns it, say `case RESET_PACKAGE_INFORMATION: return initialState;`

Comment: No, what I meant is, after saving the settings I need to put the packageTypes to the default state. 
in your example, in the RESET_PACKAGE_INFORMATION I need to make the packageType to the initial state and leave the packageList with the latest values

Comment: Then you can simply do `return Object.assign({}, state, {packageTypes: initialState.packageTypes})`

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the action you're trying to achieve this in is only the `FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS` action, and the payload is the updated/fetched list, then you just need to return an object as shown below.

Since you're trying to return an object with only one of the two properties changed, then you can use the previous state's value for the unchanged property and update the other.

```
const initialState = {
    packageList: packageListInitialState,
    packageTypes: [{title: 'Select Package Type', value: ''}],
};

export default function packageState( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch ( action.type ) {
        case FETCH_PACKAGE_LIST_SUCCESS:{
            return { packageList: action.payload, packageTypes: state.packageTypes }
        }

        case FETCH_PACKAGE_SETTINGS_SUCCESS:{
           return Object.assign( {}, state,  action.payload );
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```